# Addition of many columns that can be null in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, null, addition

I have seen this question and it works well for two columns

[Addition with NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769648/addition-with-null-values)

How do I expand it for more than 2? For example, I can sum up to 10 columns at a time, which would generate a way too long expression. If all are nulls, then the sum should return null.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the reference is a very good answer.  The better answer -- which applies in your case -- is:

```
select coalesce(a, 0) + coalesce(b, 0) + . . .
```

You can add as many variables as you like with this approach.

Note that this returns `0`, not `NULL` if all values are `NULL`.  If you want `NULL` returned, you can do:

```
select (coalesce(a, 0) + coalesce(b, 0) + . . . +
        (case when coalesce(a, b, . . . ) is not null then 0 else null end)
       )
```

This puts in an additional coefficient that is either zero or `NULL` to turn the expression back to `NULL`.

Comment: Following the logic, is there a way to define a "sumnull" operator/macro in Oracle so that I could write the same line sumnull(a,b,c,d,e...), but having an undeterminate number of columns in the sumnull operator?

Comment: @Stephane . . . I don't know if Oracle allows variable numbers of arguments for user defined functions.  It does allow default values and function name overloading, so you can pretty much get the same effect for reasonable numbers of arguments.

Comment: I'll ask that as a separate question then :)