# Adding three Integer variable shows result as Null, why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

Here is the code I tried

```
SELECT 
 case when InsertedRows is null then 0 else InsertedRows end InsertedRows
,case when FailedRows is null then 0 else FailedRows end FailedRows
,case when UpdatedRows is null then 0 else UpdatedRows end UpdatedRows
,InsertedRows + UpdatedRows + FailedRows as tot
FROM PATS.ImportLog
WHERE CreatedBy='suvaneeth' 
      AND ISNULL(CompletedYN,0) = 0 
      AND CAST(CreatedDate AS date) >= CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
```

and I get the result for `tot` is NULL

```
99  0   0   NULL
```

I'm expecting the result is 99

Comment: `NULL + 0 = NULL`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Addition with NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769648/addition-with-null-values)

Comment: there is no NULL values. All of them are converted into 0

Comment: They are on another column expressions, not on your table. You would have to repeat the whole CASE again for that matter.

Comment: The `tot` column in the result just adds them directly, without regarding to nulls. There is at least one in either of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
case when InsertedRows is null then 0 else InsertedRows end InsertedRows
,case when FailedRows is null then 0 else FailedRows end FailedRows
,case when UpdatedRows is null then 0 else UpdatedRows end UpdatedRows
,COALESCE(InsertedRows,0) + COALESCE(UpdatedRows,0) + COALESCE(FailedRows,0) as tot
from PATS.ImportLog
WHERE CreatedBy='suvaneeth' AND ISNULL(CompletedYN,0)=0 AND CAST(CreatedDate AS date)>=CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `ISNULL(insertedrows, 0)` or `COALESCE(insertedrows, 0)` instead of `CASE`

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way.

```
select 
  Coalesce(InsertedRows, 0) InsertedRows
  ,Coalesce(FailedRows, 0) FailedRows
  ,Coalesce(UpdatedRows, 0) UpdatedRows
  ,Coalesce(InsertedRows, 0) + Coalesce(FailedRows, 0)+ Coalesce(UpdatedRows, 0) as tot
from PATS.ImportLog
WHERE CreatedBy='suvaneeth' AND ISNULL(CompletedYN,0)=0 AND CAST(CreatedDate AS date)>=CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
```

Comment: There is no error message. It shows the same result what i was trying

Comment: are you sure that your where clause returns any result?